# How to set html contentEditable div of fixed width

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble getting a contentEditable element to show as a box of a fixed with (eg  2 characters wide). As it is it is the width of the padding only. Works OK when there is text in the box, but I would like to have an empty box of a certain width. Any ideas?

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="so.css" />
<body>
<h1 id="prompt">Type something in the box:</h1>
<h1 id="textarea"></h1>
</body>
```

css:

```
#prompt, #textarea{
    display:inline;
}

#textarea{
    contentEditable: true;
    width: 2em; /* 20px doesn't work either */
    cursor: text;
    background-color:rgba(132, 225, 132, 0.9);
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Comment: to size your h1, use any display, but inline, or float it . position:fixed/absolute will allow you as well to size it . only **inline will not allow** it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to set [`contentEditable="true"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) in `HTML` as attribute.

You can use **Flexbox** and set `min-width` to `#textarea` and `flex-shrink: 0;` to `#prompt`. So `#textarea` will grow but won't push `#prompt`.

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}

#prompt {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

#textarea {
  min-width: 100px;
  word-break: break-all;
  cursor: text;
  background-color:rgba(132, 225, 132, 0.9);
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1 id="prompt">Type something in the box:</h1>
  <h1 contentEditable="true" id="textarea"></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: For anyone else with this issue, adding flex-basis: 2em; (for example) to the textarea property could also be used to control it's specific width.

Answer (score 1):

Inline elements can't have width or height. You should try to let them be at least inline-blocks.

Comment: I tried this as per below also by adding display: block to the #prompt, #texarea{..} style. The result being that the textarea is put on the line below the prompt. Any way to keep on same line?